# How can I kill process by specific name and exclude root processes

Tags: process, solaris, kill, ps

Not a long time ago we found out about [`pkill`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/6mbb0m9nr/index.html) and we had in mind to start using it in a setuid (for root) script for global clean-up of processes. This could save us lots of stupid maintenance where some clients can´t remove general resources using their scripts only due not important permission limitations.

However, after some struggling we only came up with `pkill -v -u root <name>` (so far we intent to make it simple and prevent from devolving into a long and ugly script with `sed`,`awk`,`grep` and so on). Of course it doesn´t work — it just kills everything but the processes that match the given name.

Is there a any short modified version of that `pkill` command that get us the results we need?

P.S: I want to avoid any discussions about the morality of giving some sort of root power to the users.

The running OS is solaris 10, if that matters.

Comment: Please specify the constraints and aims of which processes you want killed.

Comment: Which shell do you use?

Comment: Are there any group memberships in common between the users and the process(s) that need to be killed?  If so, this might help:  http://serverfault.com/questions/325128/unix-permissions-to-allow-group-users-to-kill-each-others-processes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will generate a list of processes with the given name, and a list of processes with the given name running as root, then run `comm` to find processes in the first list that are not in the second list, then kill them.

```
#!/bin/ksh
if test $# != 1
then
    echo usage: "$0" processname
    exit 1
fi
pname="$1"
kill $(comm -23 <(pgrep "$pname"|sort -n) <(pgrep -u root "$pname"|sort -n))
```

Comment: I remember looking at it 5 years ago and was overwhelemed with the comm command. but now seeing this multiple times, this is a great solution!

Answer (score 1):

I am using SUSE , but assuming it works similar on Solaris.

### Kill process for a User

In order to kill a process by its user id You can do following

`#pkill -U <username>`

### Check processes for a User

If you just want to check what processes are running for a particular user before killing his processes, you can use:
`pgrep -U <username`

### Kill process for multiple users

`#pkill -U <user1>,<user2>,<user3>` and so on.

### Kill all users except root

I know you are avoiding sed , awk , grep. But its easier to write a script rather than having to type each user name.
Here is a sample. Please check on sanbox before executing on production.

```
ps -aef |grep -v UID |grep -v root |awk '{print $1}' 
 |sort -u |while read name
do 
echo "Killing process for user $name"
pkill -U $name
done
```

Comment: You can preview the script by replacing `pkill -U $name` with `echo "pkill -U $name" ` to make sure it works and kills right processes